# Make the Header Appear only once For Each Group

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to replicate a dropdown like [this.](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-grouping-problem-i9jtj?file=/src/App.js).

Here is my code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    header:1,
    value:1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    header:2,
    value:2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    header:2,
    value:3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    header:1,
    value:4
  }
];

useEffect(() => {
setData(data)
}[])

const renderSelectGroup = wfItem => {
        const items =
            <MenuItem key={wfItem.value} value={wfItem.value} >
                {wfItem.value}
            </MenuItem>

            return [<ListSubheader>{wfItem.header}</ListSubheader>, items];
        // return [items]
    };

return (
<Col className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 mr-auto mb-2">
    <FormControl variant="outlined" size="small" fullWidth>
          <InputLabel>Dropdown With Grouping</InputLabel>
               <MuiSelect
                   label="Dropdown with Grouping"
                   value={selectValuesWM}
                   onChange={handleWMChange}
                   >
                   {data.map(p => renderSelectGroup(p))}
                </MuiSelect>
              </FormControl>
 </Col>
)
```

So when this is rendered it looks like this:

| Header 1 |
| --- |
| Value 1 |
| **Header 2** |
| Value 2 |
| **Header 2** |
| Value 3 |
| **Header 1** |
| Value 4 |

When it should be like this:

| Header 1 |
| --- |
| Value 1 |
| Value 4 |
| **Header 2** |
| Value 2 |
| Value 3 |

The data isn't nested so I'm just not sure of the steps I should take here to get the desired outcome. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not your question, but you dont need to call the `useEffect` and `setData()` unless there is a reason for this. Instead you can directly use the `data` you defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer from @j-low](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71125022/1494989) makes good points about data structure and component breakdown so I'd recommend a combination of that answer with this. My understanding is that you are unable to modify the API payload response so that leaves you needing to do this from the React app.

The idea is to create a new object by iterating over your API response array and for each item see if it's group exists on this new object of yours. In this case, the new object is identified by the `header` value. If the group exists then append the data to a `headerData` array, otherwise, create a new group based on the `header` value and set the `headerData` to an array with the data as the first item.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Desired data format (to match @j-low answer)
  // [
  //   {
  //      header: 1,
  //      headerData: [{ id: 1, value: 1}, { id: 4, value: 4}]
  //   }
  // ]

  // `someData` is the value from API
  const formattedData = someData.reduce((acc, val) => {
    // see if group already exists
    const group = acc.find(({ header }) => header === val.header);

    if (group) {
      // add to existing group
      group.headerData.push(val);
    } else {
      // create new group
      acc.push({
        header: val.header,
        headerData: [val]
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  // `data` stat to be mapped over in component render
  setData(formattedData);
}, []);
```

I included the entire `val` object in each group `headerData` above but up to you if you want to include only specific properties.

Working example on CodeSandbox using code aligning to the question:

[image: Edit blissful-brown-8jx3z]

Comment: Nice solution Ash

Comment: Thanks @j-low it was inspired by your data format

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried out your solution and it's exactly what I was looking for. Worked flawlessly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to get exactly the data that you need, and then show the UI accordingly. Once you receive your data, you could group it by header using the following function as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433967/group-array-of-objects-by-id):

```
let filteredData = [];

_data.forEach((r) => {
  if (!filteredData[r.header]) filteredData[r.header] = [];
  filteredData[r.header].push(r);
});

const groupedData = filteredData.filter(() => true);
```

This will give you the following data:

```
const groupedData = [
 [{ id: 1, header: 1, value: 1}, { id: 4, header: 1, value: 4}]
 [{ id: 2, header: 2, value: 2}, { id: 3, header: 2, value: 3}]
];
```

Conceptually, you can then render this like so:

```
{groupedData.map((groups) => (
  <>
    <h2>Header {groups[0].header}</h2>
    {groups.map(({ id, value }) => (
      <p>
        id: {id} value: {value}
      </p>
    ))}
  </>
))}
```

To match your approach, your `SelectGroup` component can look like this:

```
const SelectGroup = ({ header, groups }) => (
  <>
    <ListSubheader>Header: {header}</ListSubheader>
    {groups.map(({ id, value }) => (
      <MenuItem key={id} value={value}>
        id: {id} value: {value}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </>
);

// and use it as such:
<MuiSelect>
   {groupedData.map((groups) => (
      <SelectGroup header={groups[0].header} groups={groups} />
   ))}
</MultiSelect>
```

Comment: The thing is, I retrieve the data from backend. And the backend gives me the data as I showed in the example. I'm just using this as an example. The JSON response from backend isn't nested so is it possible to achieve the outcome I want without altering the structure or creating a new object?

Comment: I see! It can be a bit tricky to group objects into new data structures. Ash provides a good example and I've updated my code example with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting way to solve the problem. Thank you so much.